# How to get back referral traffic from googleapis.com?

Tags: seo, google-analytics, google-search, web-traffic

My website is one year old. I was writing on my website for the last year but hardly got any traffic. But in the first week of this year, the website got huge traffic of 20k visits per day (while it was roughly 20 visits per day) for 3/4 days. Thereafter, it again started decreasing & now it reached to 200 visits per day till date. During the huge traffic, most of it was coming from googleapis.com. During that time my website was seen in the chrome home section. Still, I can't figure out how to get back that traffic or why did the traffic reduce? Can anyone help me to find out the reason? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

What you are talking about is part of the [Google Discover](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/mobile/google-discover?hl=en) program. Google simply displays content from all over the web both in Chrome suggestions + Google News, and the more users like the content, the more it will be boosted.

This only happens, of course, when you publish new articles on your website. Google will start displaying your new article for a small portion of users according to their own criteria, and if they like it (E.g click it or spend some time on it), it will be shown for thousands and thousands of more users.

Of course, your article won't stay in the suggestions section for ever. After 2-3 days at maximum, your article will fade away and open the path for new articles from other websites to come.

**How can you go back there?** Simply publish more new articles, and try to use interesting articles so that you catch the eyes of the visitors. This is your only way to get that traffic spike from time to time.

Comment: Thank you for your response :) I every day publish unique content at least 2 per day. Nowadays I see that every day 2/3 clicks come through Google discover but not more.